# Subprocess stdout to file, missing new line

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I am calling a subprocess, I want the subprocess output written to an already open file. I am using the following code:

```
f1=open('solve.out','w') 
#beginning of the programm writes to this file
f_err = open('mor.err', "w")
arguments=[file.exe,arg1,arg2,...]
p=subprocess.Popen(arguments,stdout=f1, stderr=f_err)
p.wait()
f1.close()
f_err.close()
```

This works fine as I get the realtime output from the .exe in my program. However, the outputs are all written in one single line. As standalone, the output appears with new lines.

I tried universal_newlines or the p.communicate() without success.

edit 1 : windows10 Python version 2.7.13

edit 2 : Hex file
[image]

Comment: have you tried checking the files with an hex editor? see which char is at the end of the lines? Can you [edit] to explain which OS you're running and which version of python?

Comment: Try to use a non-Windows editor (Scite, notepad++, ...) to open the files created from stdout/stderr. Windows expects `\n\r` as line ending, but Python just writes `\n`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre where I expect a line indent I get "20 20 20 20 20 20" so 6 spaces I think (I installed hex editor plugins for notepad++)

Comment: @MauriceMeyer. No, python writes `\r\n` when files are open in text mode for writing.

Comment: can you copy/paste a snippet of the hex data? or a (readable) picture if it's too complicated? and can you reproduce the problem with `dir` or another known program so we can reproduce? some programs detect when the outputs are redirected and can act differently.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I edited with the snippet. I am not sure what you meant by reproduce the pb with dir. If I do run the program directly (no subprocess) with '> solve.out' , the file is written with new lines

Comment: sounds that my hypothesis is correct: the program detects the redirection and changes the way it outputs the text.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre any idea of workaround for manually setting an inline? (It does print properly in the command prompt as well. )

Answer (score 1):

your program seems to detect that the output is being redirected to a non-console output.

There are ways to make believe to the program that it's writing to a console, but in your case there may exist a simple workaround which would be to replace 6 spaces by a linefeed. Of course this isn't perfect if spaces occur somewhere else, but that's a start.

For this you would have to first redirect to 2 separate pipes (to avoid reading/writing a file on disk), replace the spaces, then write to file:

```
p=subprocess.Popen(arguments,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output,error = p.communicate()
f1.write(output.replace(" "*6,"\n"));
f_err.write(error.replace(" "*6,"\n"));
```